# If $A = \{ 2, \frac{1}{2} , 3, \frac{1}{3} , 4, \frac{1}{4} , 5, \frac{1}{5} , . .\}$. Are $P(A \cap [0,1])$ and $P(A \cap [1,2])$ countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> If $A = \{ 2, \frac{1}{2} , 3, \frac{1}{3} , 4, \frac{1}{4} , 5, \frac{1}{5} , . .\}$. Are the following sets countable (using the definition of countable meaning to not be finite and have the same cardinallity as $\mathbb{N}$) : $P(A \cap [0,1])$ and $P(A \cap [1,2])$

Attempt at solution:

For $P(A \cap [0,1])$: $A \cap [0,1]$ is the same as $\{\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{1}{3} ,\frac{1}{4}... \}$ which is countable so the power set of a countable must be uncountable

For $P(A \cap [1,2])$: $A \cap [1,2]$ is the same as $\{2\}$ and the power set of $\{2\}$ is $\{\{2\}, \emptyset\}$which is finite so it is uncountable.

I am not sure if my solutions are correct

Comment: Uncountable usually means uncountably infinite. I prefer  countable to mean " finite or countably infinite" .

Comment: I am using the definition of countable meaning to have the same cardinallity as $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: If you call finite sets uncountable, people will be consider you to be ( at best) eccentric.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet:  I have seen countable to imply infinite a number of places.  One has to check the definition in each environment.  OP has given a definition which we should accept for this purpose.

Comment: @RossMillikan .  I  never saw a finite set called "uncountable" betore, but it $is$ consistent  with the OP's def'n of countable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: if countable is required to be in bijection with $\Bbb N$ then uncountable is everything else, which includes the finite sets.  I agree it is counterintuitive to call finite sets uncountable.  On the other hand I proved in a recent question that I could not count to four accurately so maybe even four is uncountable.  Restricting countable to infinite sets removes a lot of qualifications from theorems but adds others,  The way things are today I think everybody should state which definition they are using any time it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning for the first part is correct. For the second, I think you mean to say that $P(\{2\})=\{\emptyset,\{2\}\}$, which is *finite*.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant I have edited my post now

Comment: Finite sets are NOT uncountable! They may or may not be considered countable, depending on whether your definition of countable allows for finite sets.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is right since $A \cap [0, 1]=\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3} \cdots \} $ is equipotent to $\mathbb{N}$, so $P(A \cap [0, 1])$ is equipotent to $P(\mathbb{N})$ then is uncounbtable. The second part is wrong $P(\{2\})$ is finite countable.